# How can I put a string into multiple columns with length = 65 but not have it cut off at the middle of a word

Tags: excel

I have a column with many different character lengths. I am trying to have a formula that will take the first 65 characters and place it into one column and the next 65 and so on into the next columns.

IF the 65th character is the middle of a word, I would like for that word to go into the next column so that I do not start a column in the middle of a word.

(The length of the columns could be anything <= 65 just as long as they have the whole word and are not cut off)

**Ex:**

```
Assurance Grade Beryllium for AA and ICP, 10,000 μg/mL (10,000 PPM), 500 mL, in 5% HNO3
```

***This is what I get***

**Column1:**

```
Assurance Grade Beryllium for AA and ICP, 10,000 μg/mL (10,000 PP
```

**Column2:**

```
M), 500 mL, in 5% HNO3
```

***Ideally this is what I would like:***

**Column1:**

```
Assurance Grade Beryllium for AA and ICP, 10,000 μg/mL
```

**Column2:**

```
(10,000 PPM), 500 mL, in 5% HNO3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution.
Cell 1: `=if(len(F6)>65, left(F6,find(", ",F6,40)),F6)`
Cell 2: `=if(len(F6)>65, MID(F6,find(", ",F6,40)+2,len(F6)),"")`

Cell1 is one cell left of cell 2. Cell F6 is the cell to split here

Comment: It's very close. When I do =if(len(F6)>65, left(F6,find(",",F6,40)),F6) it stops at the ","  For example it stopped at 10, instead of 10,000. So I changed it to =if(len(F6)>65, left(F6,find(" ",F6,40)),F6) and that gave me the correct 10,000 as the last characters.

Comment: When i take out that comma after left(F6,find(" ",F6,40)),F6) it works for the first part and cuts it off at 10,000. But when I do the second formula it starts at 10,000 again instead of the μg/mL

Comment: Replace the comma(,) with a comma-space(, ) and fixed the answer above

Comment: =if(len(F6)>65, left(F6,find(", ",F6,40))"") like that?

Comment: the other thing is with the number 40 you used, does that only apply to this example?

Comment: So that 40 is finding a (, ) after 40 characters if the entire string is >65 characters. that you can certainly change that to 55 if you feel that this isn't working for other values, I only had one entry to try with, experiment with 40 and if you aren't happy increase it. I've updated the answer, copy that to experiment with.

Comment: ok. When I try to put in the second formula you gave I get an error saying: the formula you typed contains an error.

Comment: Assurance Grade Arsenic for AA and ICP, 10,000 μg/mL (10,000 PPM), 500 mL, in 5% HNO3                   Here is another example. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I pasted the same formula twice. Try now.

Comment: Plesure, please mark my answer as correct and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",65-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,65)," ",""))-1))-1)
```

And

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",65-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,65)," ",""))-1))+1,999)
```

[image]

---

By the two examples the number of words is the same.  If this is the case then the formula can be simplified:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",9))-1)
```

And

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",9))+1,999)
```